# No startup sound (I constantly need to restart PRAM)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

I have a MacBook Pro 2012 mid 13" (with the newest Yosemite update) and some time ago I noticed, that startup sound was gone. I googled a little bit and saw that resetting PRAM should solve the problem. It did. But after a few days startup sound was gone again. So I reseted PRAM once again, and it fixed the problem. Now the sound is gone again and I'm tired of reseting PRAM, I'm pretty sure that's not how it should be. Does anyone have any idea what's the problem here? Maybe that's a sign that I need to change my RAM? :s

Comment: Did you mute your speaker output at all? Boot chime is system volume-dependent. - see http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-silence-the-startup-chime-on-a-mac--cms-21212

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me all the time, if your computer is muted when it turns off it won't bong when you turn it back on (doesn't apply to restarts). A bit odd but it happens.

Comment: As designed - Boot chime is dependent on system volume

Comment: Oh my god, stupid me, thank you so much for this. I just restarted my macbook with volume up and it works! Thanks.

Comment: @Arnas Can you mark it right then?